# Auth0 "Custom Social" for Google fails with "Invalid user id."

Tags: oauth, auth0, google-identity

I setup Auth0 and Google credentials and had it working using the free trial period within Auth0. this is for a side-project so I need to switch to the free tier "Custom Social" Auth0 logins. [I followed these instructions](https://dev.to/victorioberra/auth0-custom-google-social-login-connection-1egg)  but end up with the error "Invalid user id" in both the Auth0 test page and the app I had working with the Social Login that is pre-build by Auth0.

In GCP console I created a "Client ID for Web application"

- Authorised JavaScript origins = `https://MY_TENANT.uk.auth0.com`
- Authorised redirect URIs = `https://MY_TENANT.uk.auth0.com/login/callback`

GCP "OAuth consent screen"

- Publishing status = Testing
- User type = External

App Registration (just setting this to get it working)

- Application home page = `https://auth0.com`
- Application privacy policy link = `https://auth0.com`
- Application Terms of Service link = `https://auth0.com`
- Authorised domain = `auth0.com`
- Your non-sensitive scopes = `/auth/userinfo.email`
- Test users = `my email address`

It generates

- GCP_CLIENT_ID = `XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com`
- GCP_CLIENT_SECRET = `YYY`

Over in Auth0 I created a new Custom Socal Login

- Authorization URL = `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`
- Token URL = `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`
- Scope = `openid email` (spaces set on)
- Client ID = `GCP_CLIENT_ID`
- Client Secret = `GCP_CLIENT_SECRET`
- Fetch User Profile Script

```js
function(accessToken, ctx, cb) {
  var p = {
    accessToken: accessToken,
    id_token: ctx.id_token
  };
  cb(null,p);
}
```

Pres test, Login screen displayed, select test account, then the error is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The answer

I was badly parsing the response in the fetch javascript.

the `user_id` is required, but I'd got the parsing part in my real code wrong

## How did I work it out?

I have a simple [httpDump](https://github.com/NearlyUnique/httpDump) app written in go that I use for these kinds of things, it just dumps whatever gets sent to it and returns the time.

I used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to forward my local httpDump to the internet and updated the fetch script to point to my laptop.

The http request worked, which was nice because to that point I had no idea where the error was.

I then manually called google with the token and it's response was

```json
{
  "sub": "a number",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/some_number",
  "email": "my.email@example.com",
  "email_verified": true
}
```

and not the structure I'd copied from the [Auth0 article](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/identity-providers/social-identity-providers/oauth2) I'd found.